# Http Vs. Web browser page visit duration

Tags: http, html

I wanted to know if HTTP web requests to a webpage get counted as a visit or not? I mean when I open the page in a browser analytics shows me a visitor has visited. Do http web requests count as visits?

Also with web pages we can stay on page for a specific duration (let's say 2 minutes) but with http can this be done? Like using sessions? I mean once you request a page with http, the page is parsed and then that visit should be over right?

What if we want to stay on that page for atleast 2 minutes using HTTP?

Regards,

Edit - I want to send traffic through httpwebrequests (and not IE or a browser component) and then see them as traffic in Google analytics.

Comment: Could you please provide some more information?  For example, when you describe a 'visit' are you referring to a tool such as google analytics?  Or are you use web server logs?

Comment: HTTP is a stateless protocol. By default there are no mechanism to find the visit duration with httprequest. For tracking page visits, you can use code to track it.  Also we are relying on tools like Google Analytics to know the page visit duration. 

As you said once the page is parsed to html and available to browser the httprequest is done for that resource.

I hope this clarifies

Comment: If you have scripts on the page that count the visit and perform other statistics, then no: the scripts are not executed, of course. The Server will log the request, though; it will also generate one or more Cookies that the WebRequest / WebResponse / HttpClient can store and send back when another request is performed. So, if you have server-side analytics that parse the logs, the *visit* is counted.

Comment: @MathewPaxinos I am using google analytics so want to see visits duration, time etc.

Comment: @Jimi If I use cookies then the visit is counted?

Comment: If you're using Google Analytics it won't. I think you have scripts inside the pages for those. No script is ever run when requesting a page content download with an Http request. It's the WebBrowser that interprets and executes scripts.

Comment: You may need to enhance your question to clarify your desired outcome.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP has nothing whatsoever to do with visits, sessions, or whatever natively.  It's done through cookies, php, js and other web technologies.

HTTP is a Protocol for how to send large amounts of text between a Server and a Client.  What is done around that is none of it's business.

Could you rephrase your question to give some idea of the use case and what you hope to achieve?

**Also not sure why this is tagged as VB.Net?**

Comment: edited - want to send bot traffic which shows as real traffic but don't want to use browser component. Want to use webrequests.